# Add extra left margin to a singe ListView row

Tags: android, listview, nested-lists

I need to graphically simulate a nested `ListView` with possible n levels. The only thing I need is to add left margin to the "child" based on its level. 
I think that a could achieve that with a `RelativeLayout` and a left-blank `LinearLayout` which can be hidden at level 0 and showed in level 1. Is this the only way to achieve that?

Comment: When you are adding childs to the listview, there you can set left margin for all the childs accept for the parent. i.e  you have to set left margin for all the  items accept the zeroth item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way to set margin dynamically is in your getView() method use

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
yourbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

when position is 0

Comment: I want to achieve that in the entire row, not in a single button, is It possible? And why only it is in position 0 and not in every row of the listview?

Comment: i give you just an example so i use 0 you can make condition for position where you want margin, like **if(position==0 || position==4 || position==7)** etc

Answer (score 0):

i give you just an example so i use 0 you can make condition for position where you want margin, like **if(position==0 || position==4 || position==7)** etc